# How to pass google command line flags as an argument to GDB

Tags: c++, gdb, command-line-arguments, gflags

I understand that to pass an argument to a gdb program I can run

```
r arg1 arg2 arg3
```

But I want to pass a GFLAG which has a name associated with an argument. Something like

```
r arg1="hi" arg2="there"
```

Comment: What is google command line flags?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> I want to pass a GFLAG which has a name associated with an argument.

What's stopping you?

This works:

```
gdb --args /path/to/binary --flag1=foo --flag2=bar --flag3="hi there"
```

So does this:

```
(gdb) run --flag1=foo --flag2=bar --flag3="hi there"
(gdb) run --flag1 foo --flag2 bar --flag3 "hi there"
```